# How to save form data to the database?

Tags: 8, forms

This is my form class:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: haris
 * Date: 2/23/18
 * Time: 2:43 PM
 */

namespace Drupal\poet_plugin\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class PoetForm extends FormBase
{
    public function getFormId() {
        return 'poet_plugin_form';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $form['frost_url'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield', //you can find a list of available types in the form api
            '#title' => 'Frost URL',
            '#size' => 50,
            '#maxlength' => 1000,
            '#required' => TRUE, //make this field required
        );
        $form['token'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield', //you can find a list of available types in the form api
            '#title' => 'Frost Token',
            '#size' => 50,
            '#maxlength' => 1000,
            '#required' => TRUE, //make this field required
        );

        $form['save'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#input' => TRUE,
            '#value' => 'save',

        );
        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $url=$form_state->getValue('frost_url');
        $token=$form_state->getValue('token');
        $connection = \Drupal::database();
        $connection->insert('token_url',['frost_url' => $url,'token'=> $token]);

    }
}
```

When I submit the form the `submitForm` function does not get called. What I am missing here?

Comment: Are you certain the code is not hit? Are you using a debugger?

Comment: No I am not using the debugger, but from the examples I have seen, there should be another element  in `$form['save']` array named `#submit`. I tried that as well but all in vain

Comment: The data is not getting inserted to database. Neither I am getting any error on submit

Comment: The first step is even confirming that the method is being hit or called, then you can worry about what the code is or is not doing inside of it.

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Put something like print 'in submit'; die;  in the submitForm function and you should see the being output on a white screen when you submit the form. If you see that then you're getting into the function fine and the problem is with your other code within that function